# How to create random function using a stored procedure? PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I have a procedure that adds data

```
add_price (cust_id customers.id%type,
           items_id items.id%type,
           price number);
```

and I want to create a function that for each combination of customers and items to create an additional one at random entry in the table price.

How can I do that?

Comment: i didnt undestand what are you trying to do. you want to add another record, but on what condition ?

Comment: @AliFidanli I want  from the  random  function to call the add_price (that inserts values) and creates random values for the price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a function, create a procedure and use `INSERT ... SELECT` with the `CROSS JOIN` of the `customers` and the `items` tables:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_random_prices
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO prices (customer_id, item_id, price)
  SELECT c.customer_id,
         i.item_id,
         ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,100),2)
  FROM   customers c
         CROSS JOIN items i;
END generate_random_prices;
/
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers (customer_id PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,5,42));

CREATE TABLE items (item_id PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,3,61));

CREATE TABLE prices (
  customer_id REFERENCES customers(customer_id),
  item_id     REFERENCES items(item_id),
  price       NUMBER(4,2)
);
```

Then after:

```sql
BEGIN
  generate_random_prices();
END;
/
```

The `prices` table may (randomly) contain:

> | CUSTOMER_ID | ITEM_ID | PRICE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 38.91 |
> | 1 | 3 | 39.74 |
> | 1 | 61 | 67.28 |
> | 5 | 1 | 13.92 |
> | 5 | 3 | 48.17 |
> | 5 | 61 | 70.21 |
> | 42 | 1 | 90.33 |
> | 42 | 3 | 5.7 |
> | 42 | 61 | 40.37 |

---

If you want to call your `ADD_PRICE` procedure then just take the same `CROSS JOIN` query and use a cursor loop:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_random_prices
IS
BEGIN
  FOR rw IN (SELECT c.customer_id,
                    i.item_id
             FROM   customers c
                    CROSS JOIN items i)
  LOOP
    ADD_PRICE(rw.customer_id, rw.item_id, ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,100),2));
  END LOOP;
END generate_random_prices;
/
```

*(But it will be more efficient to just use a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement.)*

*db<.fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c22bdb22d90d658cc3421e1957cfd5fe)*

Comment: That's exactly what i want.. the one with the add_price procedure. But it returns me --PLS-00402 alias required in select list of cursor to avoid duplicate column in row 4.

Comment: @GEO As you can see from the db<>fiddle linked in the question, my code does not generate that error. You need to debug your code and see what you have done differently and then you can search the internet for `PLS-00402` and read up on what causes that problem and see if you can solve it. We cannot help you without knowing what you have done differently (and it is best if you learn how to debug your own code).

Answer (score 1):

UPD: Please note, I believe the idea from MT0 is better because you'll need only one insert statement. My solution is for the case when using add_price function is required

So, "each combination of customers and items" means you need a cartesian product:

```
select cust_id, item_id
  from customers
  cross join items;
```

For example if you had following data in "customers" and "items" table:

| cust_id | cust_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

| item_id | item_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

the query above would return:

| cust_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Thus, all is left is to get random value. Use dbms_random.value for that

```
begin
  for q in (select cust_id, item_id from customers cross join items) loop
    add_price(q.cust_id, q.item_id, round(dbms_random.value(10, 1000), 2));
  end loop;
end;
```

The parameters for value are lowes_value and highest_value so the result will be between those numbers. You probably will need to set them somehow. And rounding will  be needed too